# RestKit Giving Error after installation as a Git Submodule

Tags: ios, git, restkit, git-submodules

I am installing Restkit in one of the projects as a GitSubmodule. I used [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule) link to install the Restkit. However after installation when i try to run the code i get the following error

> diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
>
> diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
>
> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the Link but still getting these error. Please can someone help me resolving these.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems to be a problem with the pods in our computers.
go to terminal and do
1) pod repo remove master
2) pod setup

The next think I did was to go inside the Reskit folder that gets downloaded from github in the first steps of the tutorial and do

1) pod update

Finally Clean and re-build the xcode project

Comment: i did but now i start getting error `can't locate file for: -lPods-RestKit`. i tried everything it is not getting installed

Comment: @shruti I am facing same issue. Did you get the answer to this ?

Comment: @ribhu. No ... at last i installed using cocoapods. and it got installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue when updating our project to Xcode 7. We were already using RestKit as a Submodule and started getting those errors about Podlock file not found etc.

Ended up deleting RestKit from our actual project, removing the framework from Target Dependencies and from Link Binary With Libraries. Then in SourceTree I clicked on the RestKit submodule and it downloaded RestKit back into my Xcode project. Re-added the RestKit framework into Target Dependencies and Link Binary With Libraries then my project compiled with no warnings.